# Run function on every table entry

Tags: javascript

I got a table that has an entry that looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]"/><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addtopath('parameter1', 'parameter2')" class="btn_addpath"> Add</a></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see every table entry countains the function "`addtopath('parameter1', 'paramter2');`"

The parameters are generated via php; so each  item is different. Also, every entry has a checkbox. This is where the trouble occurs.

I want to create a function that runs the "addtopath" function for every table item, that is checked, as if the user clicked the "Add" button.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers...

```
function runChecked() {
    var links = mytable.querySelectorAll("input[name='ids[]']:checked + a.btn_addpath");
    [].forEach.call(links, function(link) {
        link.onclick();
    });
}
```

IE8+...

```
function runChecked() {
    var inputs = mytable.querySelectorAll("input[name='ids[]']");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked)
            inputs[i].nextSibling.onclick();
    }
}
```

IE6+...

```
function runChecked() {
    var inputs = mytable.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name === "ids[]" && inputs[i].checked)
            inputs[i].nextSibling.onclick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add the parameters to data attributes in case you want to move to jQuery at some point. It's also good practice.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-one="one" data-two="two" class="btn_addpath"/>Add</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-one="three" data-two="four" class="btn_addpath"/>Add</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-one="five" data-two="six" class="btn_addpath"/>Add</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-one="seven" data-two="eight" class="btn_addpath"/>Add</td>

function addToPath(p1, p2) {
  console.log(p1, p2);
}

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_addpath');
var checkboxArr = [].slice.call(checkboxes);
checkboxArr.forEach(function (el) {
  var p1 = el.getAttribute('data-one');
  var p2 = el.getAttribute('data-two');
  el.onchange = function () {
    if (this.checked) { addToPath(p1, p2); }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can use the following code:

```
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").siblings('a').click();
```

Test it at http://jsfiddle.net/tMe46/

Comment: He never said he wants jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

This should emulate onClick event at all links in checked boxes

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked + a").click();
```

Comment: jQuery wasn't specified in the tags.

Comment: @Andy, there is not specified that jQuery cannot be used - [unconscious ignorance](http://patndoris.com/b2blog/blog4.php/unconscious-vs-conscious-ignorance-1). Your downvote is not fair :)

Comment: if the OP wanted to use jQuery he would have added a jQuery tag to the question. He didn't.